# How to clone an element and not fire events in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am attempting to clone an input element of type="file". In this input element there is an onchange event. The clone method is called in the function that is called from the onchange event.

The problem I am having is that when I clone the file upload input, the onchange event is fired again. This only happens in Chrome, but works as intended in IE.

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpLoad" onchange="doFunction();" />

doFunction = function() {
    var oldEl = $('#fileUpLoad');
    var newEl = $(oldEl).clone();
    $(oldEl).attr('id','fileUpLoadOLD');
    $(oldEl).before(newEl);
}
```

I have created a fiddle duplicating this issue. [Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/2yofue6e/)

How can I clone this file upload input without firing the onchange event again and again? I am using jQuery 1.7.1. This is actually a simplified a snippet from [ajaxfileuploader.js](https://github.com/kunashir/pricemap/blob/master/price_map/public/AjaxFileUploaderV2.1/ajaxfileupload.js):

```
var oldElement = jQuery('#' + fileElementId);
var newElement = jQuery(oldElement).clone();
jQuery(oldElement).attr('id', fileId);
jQuery(oldElement).before(newElement);
jQuery(oldElement).appendTo(form);
```

UPDATE: fiddle [I think this is accomplishing what I need](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/pefbcjkp/) based on @MichaelAngstadt answer. Still testing though.

This is what seems to be working for me in the ajaxfileuploader.js extension:

```
    var oldElement = jQuery('#' + fileElementId);
    var oldElEvents = oldElement.data("events");
    var newElement = jQuery(oldElement).attr('id', fileId).data("events", null).clone();
    jQuery(oldElement).attr('id', fileElementId).before(newElement);
    jQuery(oldElement).data("events", oldElEvents);
    jQuery(newElement).appendTo(form);
```

Comment: It might be because you clone the event binding on the element as well. Try to unbind it after `clone()` call

Comment: Using `clone( false )` would prevent a deep-copy of the element. See [the API docs here](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: @pabo I have tried both .clone(false) and .clone(false, false) to no avail :(

Comment: I'm not sure I can replicate the issue. I loaded your fiddle in Chrome 29.0.1547.65, and when I choose a file, it creates a new fileupload element. Is this not the intended behavior?

Comment: I loaded your fiddle in Chrome too.  As it stands it doesn't work (`$ is undefined`) but if I set it mto have jQuery then I get a whole bunch of inputs created   - I end up with 24 and a message in the console log saying "Range error: maximum call stack exceeded" and a stack dump showing that clone does indeed trigger change.  If I try the fiddle in Firefox it crashes my whole browser when I open the select file dialog!

Comment: @pabo I am using Chrome 36.0.1985.125, I did not have issues with this until the more recent versions of Chrome, essentially this creates an infinite loop when cloning an element which has an event bound that calls the function where the clone method is called.

Comment: @Adam yes, since it creates an infinite loop, there are issues, that is my problem. I did have jQuery 1.7.2 selected in my fiddle though, so $ should not be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always hold the events in a temporary object and re-attach them after cloning like:

```
doFunction = function(){
    var oldEl = $('#fileUpLoad');
    var oldElEvents = oldEl.data("events");
    var newEl = $(oldEl).data("events", null).clone();
    $(oldEl).attr('id','fileUpLoadOLD');
    $(oldEl).before(newEl.data("events",oldElEvents));
}
```

This way oldEl doesn't actually have events defined to be cloned.  Otherwise you'll be battling some fundamental functionality with regards to how cloning & the DOM work.

Comment: this was not exactly the answer but was so close, I basically used your thought process here and was able to accomplish what I need.. at least I think so far.

Comment: This answer does **not** work for me.  Exhibits the same problems as the original (http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/fqbxvaso/).  This removes events in the data, but the event is set via an attribute so is created from the `onchange` attribute when the element is cloned.  If you set the events via jQuery (i.e. as data) then you don't need to remove/reapply them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cloning the object using `$.extend` instead.

```
var newEl = $.extend({},oldEl);
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works in a sense, but I still need to retain the event, just not call it during the clone process.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is related to `onchange` attribute. You can remove/reset the attribute before cloning. After cloning, the `change` event is triggered again and it results in an infinite loop.

```
var newEl = oldEl.removeAttr('onchange').clone();
```

You are loading jQuery, why not using it's methods? If you are using `onchange` attribute for keeping the event handler, you can use event delegation technique instead.

```
$(document).on('change', '.fileUpLoads', function() {
     $(this).clone().insertBefore(this);
});
```

Comment: This was a great suggestion, but I tried several different variations thereof, and was still not able to get the event back to the oldEl for multiple file uploads.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer from @undefined (which works) I'd suggest actually making the change event a delegated event on a container object.  Otherwise you end up with one input (the old one) which clones itself on change and another (the new one) which doesn't.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="file" class="foo" id="fileUpLoad" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.container').on('change', '.foo', function () {
        var oldEl = $('#fileUpLoad');
        var newEl = $(oldEl).clone().val('');
        $(oldEl).attr('id', 'fileUpLoadOLD');
        $(oldEl).before(newEl);
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/aro60t24/2/)  (I have also reset the value of the new input to null)

Note: This is still crashing Firefox for me.  Not sutre why but might be my FF - the change event hasn't fired (in the other browsers) at the point FF crashes.

**Explanation**
I think what is happening here is that jQuery does not (by default) clone events when you clone an element.  It does, however, clone attributes.  So the `onchange` attribute on the element gets cloned and creates a change event on the cloned element, which for some reason is then called triggering an infinte loop.  Not sure why `.clone()` triggers change events

Events attached via `.on()` on the object are not cloned - so no extra elements but no event on them either.  By making the event a delegated event on a container we avoid the problem (since when the change event is triggered during clone the new element is not part of the page yet and so does not trigger the delegated event) but still have the functionality on the new object (once we insert it into the page).

You need better handling of the IDs if you want to be able to get more than two such inputs.

Comment: One issue with this is that you could end up with multiple elements with the same ID, `fileUpLoadOLD`.

Comment: @pabo: exactly.  hence "You need better handling of the IDs if you want to be able to get more than two such inputs."

Comment: Nice, I didn't see that. Incidentally, your fiddle does *not* crash my Firefox (OSX 31.0).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm also running 31.0 (Win 8.1) so not sure what is going on there - but nice to know it works elsewhere :)

Comment: going to try this in my actual application to see if works, what is supposed to happen is I clone the fileupload control, appending that to a new form in an iframe, reset the fileupload control from which the clone was taken for reuse, then I post the iframe to upload the file.

Comment: Ah!  OK.  So you don't want to emtpy the value or have a clone event on the new input then?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything fancy here. If you attach the onchange event with jQuery/javascript instead of in the HTML, then clone( ) will only create one copy, as desired.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpLoad" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#fileUpLoad').change( function() {
        doFunction();
    });
});

doFunction = function() {
    var oldEl = $('#fileUpLoad');
    var newEl = $(oldEl).clone( );
    $(oldEl).attr('id','fileUpLoadOLD');
    $(oldEl).before(newEl);
}
```

**P.S** `fileUpLoad`, really? That sneaky capital L in there caused me some problems.